# Reading a count of a complex object in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to make a photo album site to learn. The screen I am working on now shows a list of albums. Each album has 0 to many photos attached.

In my knockout view model, I have:

```
self.Albums = ko.observableArray([]);
```

This is populated with a list of Album objects from my api call. Each album has a List of  photos in them.

I make the call to get the albums:

```js
var urialbums = '/api/Photo/GetAlbums';
$.get({ url: urialbums, contentType: "application/json" })
    .done(function (data) {
        vm.Albums(data);
    });
```

data consist of a JSON object (I think?), which is a serialized version of this:

```cs
public class UIAlbumModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int PrivacyTypeID { get; set; }
    public string PrivacyType { get; set; }
    public List<UIPhotoModel> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, it has a list of Photos.

A photo is an object with a name and a URL to the photo.

In my view, I am showing a list of the albums with the album name. However, next to the album name, I am trying to show the number of photos in the album.

```xml
<div data-bind="foreach: Albums">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p><span data-bind="text: Name"></span> (<span data-bind="text: Photos().length"></span>)</p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"> </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it's failing on the count of photos.

> text: Photos().length

Error:

> knockout-3.4.0.js:72 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding
>   "text: function (){return Photos().length }" Message: Photos is not a
>   function

How can I get the number of child photos in the album that I'm currently foreach-ing through?

Comment: Photos isn't an observable array, but a plain array. I assume there is more to the error that might help diagnose the issue, but does `Photos.length` work?

Comment: I've added the error to the question.

Comment: Oh! And Photos.length does indeed work! That seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Photos().length` to `Photos.length`.
As the error message states, you are trying to invoke Photos as a function, but it isn't a function.